# cant upgrade npx stuck at version 9.6.2

Tags: npm, npx

When I type  npx -v I get:

> 9.6.2 .

I have tried deleting it with `"npm uninstall npx"` but it doesn't work. How do I upgrade npx to the latest version.

Comment: Does it give you an error when you [`npm update npx`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-update)? Is `npx` listed in `package.json`?

Comment: it returns "up to date" but when I do  "npx -v" or "npm npx -v" it returns 9.6.2

Comment: Is it listed in `package.json` with fixed version?

Comment: it is not listed {
  "name": "smatcher",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}